# popup close after back button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to achieve that if popup open and user cancel it and press back it should not  again open popup inside it should get back!

```
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
          setTimeout(function() {
            window.open( "#popup_flight_travlDil3" ,"_self")

           }, 1000);
                }


              </script>
```

Comment: Can you provide more information such as all of your code and your jquery version?

Comment: its basic div and css? that all i have   html <div id="popup_flight_travlDil3" class="overlay_flight_traveldil">
 <div class="popup_flight_travlDil">
   <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0605/0680/0349/files/Mcaffeine-5.jpg?v=1664169142" alt="gh" width="100%" height="80%" />
 <a class="close_flight_travelDl" href="#">&times;</a>
  <div class="content_flightht_travel_dil">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

Answer (score 1):

You can use sessionStorage

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { // or $(function() { ... in jQuery
  const popped = sessionStorage.getItem("popped");
  if (popped) return; 
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.open("#popup_flight_travlDil3", "_self")
    sessionStorage.setItem("popped",true)
  }, 1000);
})
```

Comment: not worked for me  consider me newbie if there any updation  in code do let me know

Comment: The code should work if I understand your question and assuming the code worked before. I am now rethinking and would like to know why you chose window.open, which may not work due to browsers not allowing it if not from a user event. What are you trying to achieve? That the page scrolls to the ID on load but not on reload?

Comment: i tried to come with pop and best resource I found is this window approach according to you how should I create a pop that open suddenly let say after 10 sec delay

Comment: What is it you want to show? What you have in the URL is an ID and not a page. You can show a modal dialog with the content of the element with ID and the browser will not stop you at all

Comment: all I want is to display a image as popup after 10 sec delay after user land on my page using current script  I find out that if users click back it get in loop due to id thing